# What could be causing this horizontal line static glitch in Chrome and Safari on iPhones?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, visual-glitch

Sometimes when viewing this specific web page in Chrome or Safari on my iPhone 7 plus iOS 12.2 I see a rendering glitch as seen in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZMIB.jpg. I cannot replicate this in a desktop browser or on my ipad, also iOS 12.2. I've seen the problem replicated on other iphones.

I've tried researching this problem but am not finding anywhere this is documented. 
Based on the responses I've read for some problems that sound similar, I've tried using transform: translate3d(0,0,0); in the CSS to "force hardware acceleration" but that didn't stop the glitch.

This is an intermittent problem. It doesn't happen on every page load and aside from constantly refreshing the page until I see it, there doesn't seem to be any reliable steps to replicate the issue.

Have any of you ever seen this type of rendering glitch and what do you call it? What was causing it?

UPDATE:
I was using the CSS property filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)); to apply drop shadows to all of the elements of a parent div. When I removed this property that seems to have cleared up the glitch.

Comment: Gotta say, never seen anything like that before... it looks like you threw a shoe at an old CRT tv and messed up the v-sync. Any chance you could provide a link to the actual site, so we could test it with different browsers and set-ups? I know this may not be possible, but I will admit, i'm curious.

Comment: I know it would be helpful to see the code, but I'm going to hold off posting the website because I don't want to draw attention to the company at this point. If there's not much of a response in the next few days I'll consider posting the link. I know it would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: It's all good. I understand not wanting to publicize. As far as I can tell, this has something to do with the way iOS handles webGL. I've read in some places that if the size of the content of the element being rendered is greater than 10mb, this can cause something similar to what you're experiencing. That being said, I do agree that elements > 10mb are rare, and therefore this is likely not the specific problem in your case. Regardless, in lieu of any other explanation, I believe some strange interaction between  webGl and iOS is your culprit.

Comment: I started looking for and disabling non-standard CSS properties. By non-standard I mean anything beyond simple sizing or coloring. I started with the transform: translate3d properties I added when first trying to find a fix for this. When I disabled the filter: drop shadow property I was applying to the content wrapper I found that I was no longer seeing the glitch. I still don't know why this was causing the glitch, I see that property is supposed to be compatible with iOS, but not for SVGs. There are SVGs on this page, but not in the content wrapper that the property was applied to.